# C# detecting key event in all windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, focus, keyevent

Hey, i have some problem with key event handler. This is source:

```
using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System.Threading;

        namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
                public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);


        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;


                public void Form1_KeyPessed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
                    {
                        DrawSquare();
                    }
                }

                public void DrawSquare()
                {
                    int line = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
                    int time = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);

                    int x = MousePosition.X;
                    int y = MousePosition.Y;
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x - line / 2, y - line / 2);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(time);
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x - line / 2, y + line / 2);
                    Thread.Sleep(time);
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x - line / 2, y + line / 2);
                    Thread.Sleep(time);
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x + line / 2, y - line / 2);
                    Thread.Sleep(time);
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x - line / 2, y - line / 2);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(time);
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
                }
            }      
        }
```

Now it only draws square when i press F2 in form, but i want it to work on all windows.
What should i need more?
(this is kinda auto drawer for perfect shapes)

Comment: Interesting note on the [documentation for `mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260.aspx). It says: **This function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) instead.**

Comment: Why did you remove the tags that I added? More tags help to classify your question so that others can find it. It also helps people who answer questions to locate it. They often follow particular tags that they're knowledgeable in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to handle a couple key combinations, you can use [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx).  If you want to detect all different key events, go with [the global hook as Paul suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450362/c-detecting-key-event-in-all-windows/5450388#5450388).

Comment: I'd not come across RegisterHotKey before but that seems a much simpler solution for this usecase...

Comment: @Paul: Yes, indeed. Your global hook solution is an excellent one, and one that I use all the time. But for a simple hotkey, it's a bit like using a bazooka to kill a fly. It will work, but it's certainly overkill and will actually hurt overall performance. Global hooks [should really be used sparingly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959.aspx). Of course, the Windows API is so large that I frequently forget about `RegisterHotKey` when answering questions myself... :-)

Comment: can you make a simple example, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need a global hook. There's a brilliant implementation here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx